# Clean way to create 'n-digit precision' float child class in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, floating-point

I want to create a `LimitedPrecisionFloat` class that would allow me to store a float with n-digits (I don't want to round the number, just cut the remaining digits). This is how I would like it to behave:

```
a = LimitedPrecisionFloat(3.45678, ndigits=3)
print(a)  # 3.456
a += 0.11199
print(a)  # 3.567
a -= 0.567999
print(a)  # 3 (or 3.0 or 3.000)
print(a + 1.9999)  # 4.999

# same with other arithmetic operators, ie.
print(LimitedPrecisionFloat(1.11111 * 9.0, 3)  # 9.999

...
```

What I currently have is:

```
def round_down(x:float, ndigits:int):
    str_x = str(x)
    int_part = str(int(x))
    fraction_part = str_x[str_x.find('.') + 1:]
    fraction_part = fraction_part[:ndigits]

    return float(int_part + '.' + fraction_part)


class LimitedPrecisionFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, x, ndigits:int):
        return super(LimitedPrecisionFloat, cls).__new__(cls, round_down(x, ndigits))

    def __init__(self, x, ndigits: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.ndigits = ndigits

    def __add__(self, other):
       return round_down(float(self) + other, ndigits=self.ndigits)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return round_down(float(self) - other, ndigits=self.ndigits)

    # other operators
```

However, this will not work, because whenever `__add__` (or any other operator) is called, it returns float and the precision is back in the number. So when I tried doing something like this:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return LimitedPrecisionFloat(float(self) + other, ndigits=self.ndigits)
```

But then I got the max recursion depth error.
Because of that, I also don't have a clue on how to implement augmented arithmetic assignments, like `__iadd__`.

Comment: It think you should not be using `float` at all for this. Use `decimal` instead.

Comment: it works using `def __add__(self, other): return LimitedPrecisionFloat(float(self) + other, ndigits=self.ndigits)`. What input did you use to obtain the max recursion depth error?

Comment: I get the same issue as OP when running the sample code provided - the result that should be 3.000 is instead 2.9990010..., so it doesn't match the goal of maintaining the rounding.

Comment: @willcrack it indeed does... turns out I changed my code a few times and meant to say that
`return LimitedPrecisionFloat(self + other, ndigits=self.ndigits)` doesn't work (notice that there is no cast to float on self)...

Comment: @trish_s I'm not sure anymore, it seems to work fine for me after all

Comment: The error makes sense without the cast. so the probelm is solved? or is 2.999 not the pretendend output?

Comment: It is! To get that 3.0 instead of 2.999, also `other` needs to be rounded, like this: `return LimitedPrecisionFloat(float(self) + round_down(other, self.ndigits), self.ndigits)` Of course, + is only an example right here